# What should I expect for navigate buttons in react using react-testing library

Tags: react-hooks, react-testing-library

I don't understand what should I expect for navigate button in the below code. can any one help me with this. Thank you.

code:

```
import react from 'react';

const HomeButton = (props) => {

const history = props.history;
function handleClick() {
  history.push("/home");
}

return (
  <button type="button" onClick={handleClick} data-testid="goToHome">
  Go home
  </button>
);
}

export default HomeButton;
```

This is the test code I have been trying for the above component

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import GoToHome from '../GoToHome';

describe('Read only text', () => {

const history = createMemoryHistory();

it('text came from props', () => {
const { container } = render(<GoToHome history={history} />);

 const goToHome = screen.getByTestId('goToHome')
 fireEvent.click(goToHome, jest.fn())

expect(container).

});
});
```

Comment: Can you post the whole component, instead of pieces of it, please ?

Comment: I have made some modifications and added test code. Please look into it

Answer (score 0):

you can check my passing the `history` as a prop with `push` property assigned to `jest.fn` as mock function and check if it is getting called when you press to navigate button

```
describe('Read only text', () => {

const mockPush = jest.fn()
const history = {
    push: mockPush()
}

it('text came from props', () => {
  const { container } = render(<GoToHome history={history} />);
  const goToHome = screen.getByTestId('goToHome')
  fireEvent.click(goToHome)

  expect(mockPush ).toBeCalled()

 });
});
```